# How do I pass an Eloquent model to a Knockout.js view model constructor?

Tags: javascript, laravel, knockout.js, eloquent

I have a solution (see below), but it's awkward and klunky & I'd like to hear how others have solved this problem.

Here's a simple example to illustrate the problem:

Imagine I have an Eloquent `User` model and I'm putting together an "edit user" page that uses [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) to handle value-to-DOM-element bindings.

In my controller method for this page, I'm doing the following:

```
public function getEditUser($id = null)
{
    return View::make("account.edituser")
        ->with("user", User::find($id))
        ->with("groups", Group::all());
}
```

where the `Group` model is for my access control groups. The user can be a member of zero or more groups and the relationship is set up in the normal way for Eloquent models.

In the template, I have a bunch of elements (text, select, radio buttons, etc.) set up with `data-bind` attributes to bind my Knockout view model to the elements.

In the `<script>` portion of the page, I have the following:

```
var createUserViewModel = function (user, groups) {
    return {
        id: ko.observable(user.id),
        name: ko.observable(user.name),
        groups: ko.observableArray(user.groups),
        // ...other attributes go here

        // the list of available groups
        availableGroups: ko.observableArray(groups)
    };
};

// instantiate the view model
var viewModel = createUserViewModel(
    // note that I'm using Smarty for my templating system. The
    // lines below apply the json_encode method and disable the
    // htmlspecialchars function which I have set up to encode
    // all output by default
    {$user|json_encode nofilter},
    {$groups|json_encode nofilter}
);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The `user` argument to the `createUserViewModel` function will be JSON-encoded, so it will look like this: `{ id: 1234, name: "Joe Smith", groups: ['group1', 'group2'], ...}`

This is a simple example: I have several forms for entering other information which are significantly more complicated than this.

There are a couple of problems with this:

1. As I said, it's awkward. The source generated by this is difficult to read for larger models.
2. I suspect there's an XSS vulnerability here, since I'm echoing data via `json_encode` directly into the body of the script element. I haven't been able to exploit this, but I think someone else could find a way.

But I can't think of another way to do it that doesn't radically change the way the application works (ie. use AJAX calls to retrieve the data).

Can anyone share a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Re (1) you need to look at the very useful mapping which is designed for exactly this - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html ... this will replace the createUserViewModel function for you, and save you having to manually turn a JSON object into something observable.

Re (2) I'm not expert enough with security and XSS to give an authoritative answer, but it looks OK to me. So long as the user and group data was sanitised before you stored it, then it should be OK to echo it back as JSON. If you're not providing a textbox or other input for a user to type into that then affects this data then there's no angle for an attacker to inject a malicious script. Plus JSON-encoding itself is quite a good sanitisation, in that any JavaScript will just end up as a string. So to be sure, given:

```
{$user|json_encode nofilter}
```

will print out some JSON, you could immediately try JSON.parse on it:

```
var user = JSON.parse({$user|json_encode nofilter})
```

before you then do anything with it in your script.

Comment: I've seen that stuff on mapping before, but didn't look too closely at it. I'll have another look. Thanks!

Comment: Have a good read of the advanced usage section - that will help you understand whether or not this will deal with your more complex models. It will certainly handle the examples you give above.